# How to make the URLs of the website SEO friendly?

Tags: php

the urls are like this https://example.com/xyz.php

i want it to change

https://example.com/xyz

PLease give me answer how can i create a htacess file

Comment: Please read the FAQ to know how to ask questions here. This is clearly the wrong approach. Also, try to use the search and/or google, since this is already answered a dozen times.

Comment: You can't do your need. There is a difference between pointing a file and pointing a folder. the xyz.php is the file and /xyz is the folder. You can't do this. Only was is redirecting.

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen This is possible with URL rewriting..

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflox, please read about URL Rewriting. StackOverflow is here to help you out on certain problematics once you have done research by yourself first hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you to make your *.htaccess* file work with URL rewriting, your **Apache HTTP Server** must have a *mod_rewrite*, and use these directives in your *.htaccess* file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```